# Moq - What happens when using It.IsAny in a setup's return?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am performing unit tests in C# using Moq. One test in particular I have created an interface wrapper over `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` so that it can be mocked.

```
public class SmtpClient : ISmtpClient
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public ICredentialsByHost Credentials { get; set; }
    public bool EnableSsl { get; set; }

    public void Send(MailMessage mail)
    {
        var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Host,
            Port = Port,
            Credentials = Credentials,
            EnableSsl = EnableSsl
        };

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

In my tests of this wrapper, to ensure that the method `Send()` is called, I have mocked the interface, and in setting up the mock, I'm using the `Setup()` to assign values to the properties of that object. In all documentation, I see that the `.Return()` of those setups are returning a specific value of the type that these methods are expecting. However, before I understood it further, I instead used `It.IsAny<T>` in the returns.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    _smtpClientMock = new Mock<ISmtpClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _smtpClientMock.Setup(x => x.Port).Returns(8080);
    _smtpClientMock.Setup(x => x.EnableSsl).Returns(false);
    _smtpClientMock.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns("host");
    _smtpClientMock.Setup(x => x.Credentials).Returns(It.IsAny<NetworkCredential>());

    _smtpClientMock.Setup(mockSend => mockSend.Send(It.IsAny<MailMessage>()));
}

[TestMethod]
public void WithValidMailMessageObject_WhenSendIsCalled_EmailClientCallsSmptClientToSendEmail()
{
    //Arrange

    //Act
    _smtpClientMock.Object.Send(new MailMessage());
    //Assert
    _smtpClientMock.Verify(checkMethodIsCalled => checkMethodIsCalled.Send(It.IsAny<MailMessage>()), Times.Once);
}
```

What I've noticed is that the tests passed. Since I haven't seen this elsewhere, I understand that this is not best practice. What I'm asking, is why is this not used, and what problems can come up with using `It.IsAny<T>()` inside the `Return` of a Moq's `Setup()` or a mocked object?

Comment: it is meant to be used in the moq expressions for filtering arguments. when passed as a value outside of the setup or verify expressions it passes the default value of the generic argument. so for reference types it will pass null

Comment: the fact that the send method is called, doesn't mean that your code that sends email is actually working. You are spending too much time worrying about something that's pretty much irrelevant. Unit test functionality, testing that a method is called is not that relevant.

Comment: That test is technically only testing that the mocking framework behaves as expected.

Comment: If everyone can understand that according to my question, the actual test and what is being tested is not relevant. Considering that there were no other examples found online, I threw together the most simple test to demonstrate the use of a 'It.IsAny()' in a return. The only thing to take away from this test, is that using IsAny in the return does not fail the test.

Comment: it does not fail the test in this scenario. that is the only take away from what you have presented

Comment: @Nkosi I feel like that answers my question fairly well. Would you mind posting that as an answer? Also to understand, IsAny in the return is passing a null value, but still the type that is designated, so it should still pass in all circumstances, or there are clear circumstances where it will not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`It` is meant to be used in Moq expressions for the filtering and matching of arguments.

> Allows the specification of a matching condition for an argument in a method invocation, rather than a specific argument value. "It" refers to the argument being matched.

`It.IsAny<T>()` is typically used when the actual argument value for a method call is not relevant. When passed as a value outside of the `Setup` or `Verify` expressions `It.IsAny<T>()` passes the default value of the generic argument. So for reference types it will pass *null* and so forth.

While in your scenario it does not fail, it is generally advised not to use the `It` class for anything other than matching arguments passed to mocked dependencies.

One typically uses the `Returns` to return a value of use when exercising a test. If a subject under test is expecting a value when a mock is invoked and instead the mock was `Setup` to return `It.IsAny<T>()`, then the test would behave in an unexpected manner.

Given the following simple example

```
public interface IDependency {
    string SomeMethod();
}

public MyClass {
    public bool MyMethod(IDependency input) {            
        var value = input.SomeMethod();

        var result = "Output" + value.ToUpper(); //<-- value should not be null

        return result != null;
    }
}
```

The following test will fail with a `NullReferenceException` because of the improper use of `It.IsAny<T>()`

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMethod_Should_Return_True() {
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IDependency>();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.SomeMethod()).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
    var subject = new MyClass();
    var expected = true;

    //Act
    var actual = subject.MyMethod(mock.Object);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass arguments from SomeMethod() to SomeOtherMethod() in the Returns(). Something of the sort:  mock.Setup(_ => _.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))                .Returns(SomeOtherMethod(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()));