# Mocked interface is returning null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm pretty new with using Moq and I'm running into an issue were one of my method calls is returning null despite the fact that I have mocked it.

I am mocking the following interfaces.

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create(KnownDbContexts knownDbContexts);
}

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    Task SaveChanges();

    IRepository Repository { get; }
}
```

Then in my unit test code it looks like this.

```
_uowFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<KnownDbContexts>()))
            .Returns(It.IsAny<IUnitOfWork>());
```

The code I'm testing looks like this.

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create(KnownDbContexts.UserDefined1))
{
    // At this point 'uow' is null.
}
```

Why is IUnitOfWorkFactory.Create returning null?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761943/moq-what-happens-when-using-it-isany-in-a-setups-return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, the method Create of the mocked factory returns an object of type `It.IsAny<IUnitOfWork>`.

However you want your mocked factory to return a **mock** of the unit of work, as such:

```
var uowMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
// here mock uowMock's methods (ie SaveChanges) in the same way it is done below for the factory

_uowFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<KnownDbContexts>()))
        .Returns(uowMock.Object);
```