# Unit testing service Moq setup not returning value

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am trying to write a unit test for my service layer.
This is the test that i am writing. I am trying to get back a response and i am having an issue with mocking. When i debug the saveCustomerRecordTextFile.WriteToDiskCustomerRecordAsync method return null and i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
  public class InvitationServiceTests
  { 
    private readonly Mock<ITranformToCustomerDistanceRecord> _customerRecordFileReader;
    private readonly Mock<ISaveInviteeRecord> _customerRecordFileOutputWriter;
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerDistanceFromDublinOffice> _distanceFromDublinOffice;
    private readonly Mock<ISaveCustomerRecord> _saveCustomerRecordTextFile;
    public InvitationServiceTests()
    {
        _customerRecordFileReader = new Mock<ITranformToCustomerDistanceRecord>();
        _customerRecordFileOutputWriter = new Mock<ISaveInviteeRecord>();
        _distanceFromDublinOffice = new Mock<ICustomerDistanceFromDublinOffice>();
        _saveCustomerRecordTextFile = new Mock<ISaveCustomerRecord>();
   }

[Fact]
public void InvitationService_return_statusOk()
{

    _saveCustomerRecordTextFile.Setup(c => c.WriteToDiskCustomerRecordAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<string>()));

    var invitationService = new InvitationService(_customerRecordFileReader.Object,
        _customerRecordFileOutputWriter.Object,
        _distanceFromDublinOffice.Object,
        _saveCustomerRecordTextFile.Object);

    var s = invitationService.InviteToDublinOfficeAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile>());

}
```

Code Implementation:

```
    public class InvitationService : IInvitationService
    {
        private readonly ITranformToCustomerDistanceRecord _customerRecordFileReader;
        private readonly ISaveInviteeRecord _customerRecordFileOutputWriter;
        private readonly ICustomerDistanceFromDublinOffice _distanceFromDublinOffice;
        private readonly ISaveCustomerRecord _saveCustomerRecordTextFile;

        public InvitationService(
            ITranformToCustomerDistanceRecord customerRecordFileReader, 
            ISaveInviteeRecord customerRecordFileOutputWriter,
            ICustomerDistanceFromDublinOffice distanceFromDublinOffice,
            ISaveCustomerRecord saveCustomerRecordTextFile)
        {   
            _customerRecordFileReader = customerRecordFileReader ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerRecordFileReader)); 
            _customerRecordFileOutputWriter = customerRecordFileOutputWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerRecordFileOutputWriter));
            _distanceFromDublinOffice = distanceFromDublinOffice ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(distanceFromDublinOffice));
            _saveCustomerRecordTextFile = saveCustomerRecordTextFile ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(saveCustomerRecordTextFile));

        }
        public async Task<InviteeResponse> InviteToDublinOfficeAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
           var filepath =  await _saveCustomerRecordTextFile.WriteToDiskCustomerRecordAsync(file);
           var customerRecords = _customerRecordFileReader.MappingFromTextFileToCustomerRecord(filepath);
           var customerRecordsWithDistance = _distanceFromDublinOffice.TransformCustomerRecordToInviteeDistanceRecord(customerRecords);
           return  _customerRecordFileOutputWriter.WriteToDiskInviteeToOffice(customerRecordsWithDistance);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<string>()));` you should not use It class in return statement 
[Moq - What happens when using It.IsAny in a setup's return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761943/moq-what-happens-when-using-it-isany-in-a-setups-return)

Replace it with any value you want like String.Empty or smthn

Comment: Link-only answers should be considered as comments